# What's the best practice when creating multiple @InvocableMethods that can be used in a flow?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I would like to know if there are any best practices when building multiple `@InvocableMethod`s for a Salesforce flow. As of now, Salesforce limits only 1 `@InvocableMethod` per apex class.

`Only one method per type can be defined with: InvocableMethod`

Is my only option to create an Apex class for each `@InvocableMethod`?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I've complained to at least one product manager (PM) at salesforce.com about this restriction. I think it's silly that we can't have multiple methods in the same class, given the UI could just list the methods. That said, you are correct in assuming that, at least for now, you must use a separate class for each invocable method. I guess the only real "best practices" that come to mind are to name your classes consistently so that they make sense in the UI, make sure you use the appropriate `category` for them to appear in, and provide a description.

Comment: You're right, this is silly! Thanks for confirming at least.

Comment: The other recommendation I have is to have these methods delegate to a separate class to do the actual processing. That way, if there are a number of related invocable methods their implementation code can all be in one class, with the invocable method classes simply calling on through to this common class.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: There is good idea-- feel free to upvote https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeuIUAR/allow-multiple-invocable-methods-in-a-single-class

Comment: @kurunve codefriar and I came up with a way to work within the limitations. See Kevin's [blog post](https://codefriar.com/universal-invocable) for more info. Would be great to have native support, though.